# Chrome extension changes DOM to iframe on click

Tags: angular, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extensions, where I inject an Angular application as an iframe. The problem is that when I interact with my Angular application, the entire DOM/document changes to only have my iframe in scope instead of having the whole website as scope.

I am sending a message from my Angular component, to remove some styling when I click on a button. It receives the message perfectly, but when i try to access the DOM I now only can access the iframe instead of the website that the user is visiting...

So in short when I try to access the DOM in content-script.js I am able to capture the entire website, but as soon as I interact with my Angular application I am only able to capture the iframe inside of the content-script.js....

Where have I gone wrong, and does anyone have an idea of what I could try to fix this?

This is my content-script.js

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
   if (request.removeClicked) {
    console.log(document)//expect this to be webpage and not iframe.
    sendResponse({ removed: true });
   }
   });
```

This is how I inject the iframe:

```
    const iframeElement = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframeElement.sandbox.add("allow-same-origin");
    iframeElement.sandbox.add("allow-scripts"); 
    iframeElement.sandbox.add("allow-popups");
    iframeElement.sandbox.add("allow-forms");

    iframeElement.setAttribute('style', 'width: 100%; height: 100%;');
    iframeElement.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(contentPath);

    document.body.appendChild(iframeElement);    
     });
    }
```